# Complex Type: Templating the datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, templating

I have two complex classes and one these classes is used in the other one. So I have a collection of cars. Each car has some properties which I like to display in columns, but each car has also a list of complex objects, which are in this case our wheels.

```
public class Car
{
    private List<Wheel> wheels;

    public List<Wheel> Wheels
    {
        get { return wheels; }
        set { wheels = value; }
    }

}

public class Wheel
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

}
```

The viewmodel looks like this

```
public class CarFactoryViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Car> cars;

    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return cars; }
        set { cars = value; }
    }
}
```

And I bind the ItemsSource of the datagrid to the cars, all primitive types will be displayed correctly, but not the wheels. So how can I templating a cell for all objects of type *Wheel*.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CarFactoryViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=Cars}"/>
</Grid>
```

I've tried already to use an DataTemplateSelector, but I get only the content of datarowview, but I like to get Wheel object. So maybe there is more simplier solution. I like simply fill the cell with the concatenation of Wheels.Name strings.

**EDIT**

I tried the following, but I can not getting the Wheel.Name property. Is there a trick for iterating the Wheels Collection and concatenate the strings? Another issue is the filtering/replacing of the column does not work.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=Cars}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Wheels}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Wheels.Count}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Result is:

[image]

**MY SOLUTION**

Using another control within the DataTemplate for example the ItemsControl. If you like to have a more customized solution then create a new control.

```
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Wheels}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

If you knows the exact count of items in collection then you could use a MultiBinding.

```
<TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Wheels[0].Name"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Wheels[1].Name"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
```

**OPEN QUESTIONS**

- How to set the datatemplate for a column if the corresponding datatype is `List<Wheels>`? So how to filter this case and setting the template?

Comment: Which control are you using to show List of wheels?

Comment: Currently, I have no special template for a Wheel or a List of Wheels defined, because I don't know how. And I don't know how I can access/passing this Wheel object within a datagrid.

Comment: You can add another property in VM like "CommaSeperatedWheelNames" which will have only get the part and it will form string out of wheels collection. Then you can simply bind same property with Datagrid in XAML.

Comment: what you want is not clear. displaying the number of wheels or all properties ? either you create a property in the car view model "wheel_count" or you must use a master/detail gui to display items under the cars